# Is a primary button on the right which receives focus first irritating?

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, accessibility

Our Design System wants primary buttons on the right, secondary buttons on it's left. This is especially great if the primary button will continue to the next step of the form.

At the same time our accessibility guidelines want focus to jump to the primary button before the secondary buttons, which seems legit as well.

**Does anybody have some test results whether this is terribly irritating to keyboard users?**

We could use `flex-direction: row-reverse` to implement it.

```css
.button-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.button-primary {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
Last input of form
<input type="text" />
</label>
  <p class="button-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="button-primary">
    <input type="button" value="Save" class="button-secondary">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Be aware that row/column reverse create a disconnect between visual and source order and may fail [WCAG 1.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-sequence.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with focusing the primary action before the secondary action here.

People often misinterpret [WCAG 1.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#meaningful-sequence) to mean that every item on a page must exactly follow the DOM order.

It is a little more nuanced than that. What 1.3.2 covers is that you must not change the meaning of the page. So if you had a block of text and used absolute positioning to reorder that text visually this would break the ordering for someone using a screen reader.

If you look at [Understanding 1.3.2 guidance](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-sequence.html) you will see an example that may surprise you and is semi-related to what you are doing:

**Examples of Success Criterion 1.3.2** - Example 2: CSS is used to position a navigation bar, the main story on a page, and a side story. The visual presentation of the sections does not match the programmatically determined order, **but the meaning of the page does not depend on the order of the sections**.

As you have correctly identified the buttons so that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> does submit the form (`type="submit"` and `type="button"` respectively) the expected behaviour is there for keyboard users anyway.

The only thing I would point out is that a lot of [people who use a screen reader still use internet explorer](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey8/#browsers), so perhaps have a fallback style sheet that uses `float: right` here that is conditionally loaded for IE as support for `flex` is not good in IE.

Comment: Cool, I didn't knew that, I always thought DOM order and focus order should be the same as part of a11y.

Comment: hm I didn't understand that Graham opposed to that. It's about visual order vs. DOM order. The tab order will always follow DOM order, except for if you work with manual tab indices > 0.

Comment: @Andy is right, DOM order and tab order should be the same as you say. However **visual** order vs DOM order can, in circumstances be different. This is a prime example, where the OP is using `flex-direction: row-reverse` to change the visual order, but their DOM order and Tab order are as they should be.

Comment: Implicit submission with `ENTER` was making me think whether experienced keyboard users would rather use that over focussing the primary button to submit – I would be interested in empirical data. (:

Comment: Probably, also for screen readers `Enter` is far more likely to be used than the buttons. I would always submit with `Enter` if the form was familiar to me.

Comment: But how would a screen reader user know if any given input is the last one in a form? Afaik screenreaders don't announce it.

Comment: That's why I said familiar to me. Also when you enter a form it does tell you how many fields there are with verbose settings on NVDA. You also get to know the pattern of things like contact forms and tend to fill in the essentials (name, email, message) and then hit enter, you then see if there are any errors or if the form has submitted correctly. Yet again we are talking experienced users here.

Answer (score 1):

This actually the correct implementation. I did something like this in one of my project on Modal window and was much liked by client as well as user.